# Translation of a website based on client's country using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, web, location

My project manager asked me to develop a website so it can change the website language dynamically based on the client's location

I searched for API's that provide the country for the client depending on his IP address and I found ipinfo.io API that sends you a JSNode containing all the information required about the client's location and now I can do the manipulation based on that

The question is what mechanism should I follow so it can get me the best performance.
I thought of two ways to translate the site:

1. should I copy all pages and make them all in Arabic and in English and redirect the client to the right page depending on his language
2. or making two files one contains Arabic elements and one for English elements and then on page load event I choose the right file based on client's country

Is there a better mechanism?

Comment: Do *not* use the location but rather the browser settings to detect the language.

Comment: Some clients will be using the browser in english but they still need the website to be translated to arabic ..

Comment: Some clients might be in an Arabic-speaking country but don't speak the language at all. You cannot just change your location, but changing the browsers settings is very easy. So your language detection should adapt to that.

Comment: I think you are right .. what about the mechanism of doing that..  did you read the last paragraph i wrote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    window.navigator.languages


please use the browser language
```

Comment: As i said .. Some clients will be using the browser in english but they still need the website to be translated to arabic

Comment: Actually this one can be used as an heuristic in case of modern browsers like chrome the first one in `window.navigator.languages` is what user has chosen as the highest preference, so if you find anything except 'en-US' (wiz. the default) at the 1st position (like `["it","en-US", "en"]`) would mean  user has configured and prefers page in that language(Italian). look chrome://settings/languages changing order here changes the array